# How do I switch two elements of a string that are seperated by an underscore?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I realize that string are immutable and that I would need to create a new String but I'm not sure how to proceed forward with that information. I've attached what I have so far and the instructions, any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm7wv.png

Comment: The String class has a split method.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-

Comment: Split the string using String.split("_"), which will return you a String[] that you can loop over and build the resulting string backwards.

Comment: Please do not include text as images. Paste the text into the question, formatting with "{}" as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String email = "mike_tyson@gmail.com";

    String[] parts = email.split("@");
    if (parts.length <= 1)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid format");

    String[] nameParts = parts[0].split("_");

    String result = email;
    if (nameParts.length >= 2) {
        result = nameParts[1] + "_" + nameParts[0] + "@" + parts[1];
    }

    System.out.println("Swapped email is: " + result);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String.split`, but that takes a regular expression. And, you could use a regex that checks for an `_` before `@` and groups the matches. Once you've done that you can use `replaceAll` to perform the swap. Since it won't operate on the String if there isn't a match you can do it one operation. Like,

```
Stream.of("mike_tyson@gmail.com", "barrakobama@gmail.com").forEach(
        s -> System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^(.+)_(.+)@", "$2_$1@")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (cleaner & better) solution:

```
public static String swap(String email) {
    int i1 = email.lastIndexOf('@');
    if (i1 < 0)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Illegal format");

    int i2 = email.indexOf("_");
    if (i2 < 0 || i2 >= i1)
        return email;

    return email.substring(i2 + 1, i1) + "_" + email.substring(0, i2) + email.substring(i1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only one '_' forming the name you can revert the names in this way (using the indexOf also)

```
    int indx = st.indexOf('@');
    String[] arrSt = st.substring(0,indx).split("_");
    String newName = arrSt[1] + "_" + arrSt[0];
    // and here you add the rest of the email part starting at @
```